# Can i print or save a pdf of all activities

Tags: civireport, activities

I need to print or save as a pdf all activities for any of our contacts on civi.  This would be used to report to meetings etc on work we have done with individuals who use our support services.  at the moment, i am printing each individual activity, which is laborious and time consuming!  is there any way i can generate a report that lists all activities?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there isn't an easy solution in CiviCRM, and if you are on Drupal, then I would recommend doing it with the Views module and the Print module which lets you generate PDFs from Views. Happy to provide more detail if that route is useful for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, really helpful, im extremely tech-ignorant so would appreciate any help to do this, for example, how do i know if im on drupal??!

Comment: Hi - so your CiviCRM will likely either be linked to a WordPress or Drupal or Joomla CMS (content management system) which is what provides the website you use to access civicrm. A quick way of checking is to see which of the following paths you can get to. I think the following is correct though some sites can block you getting to them. But you must be using one of these to log in to your civicrm system I would think

<yoursite.com>/user   means you have a Drupal site

<yoursite.com>/admin (or wp-admin)   means you are on WP

<yoursite.com>/administrator   means you are on joomla

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. The Constituent Detail Report was made for this kind of purpose.  Search for the contact you are meeting with, and it will show their relationships, contributions, activities, and more.  However, if you keep notes in the Detail field on your activities, this won't be very helpful as it doesn't display.
2. You can use the Activities report to display all of the client's activities.  Again, just filter to the appropriate contact, and you can even filter your activity type.  Though not a real "contact" report, you'll find this under Reports > Contact Reports.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, really helpful, as you suggested i do need to display all the detail within the activities, will have a go!